# Suggestions for efficient methods to hold HTML Canvas Image Data in memory?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvas

I'm currently in the process of writing a point and click adventure game using TypeScript and Electron (outside of work FWIW). Now that I have the basic structure with some user input and graphics routines up and running, I've turned my attention to optimising what I have so I can leave it in the background and move on to the next stage in the process.

Right now I merely create a new `Image()` object with its "src" attribute set to my desired PNG, and hold the resulting `HTMLImageElement` in memory. I then draw the element to the canvas using `drawImage` on every frame.

Throwing PNGs to the canvas every frame feels wrong and inneficient. What would be the best way to hold image data in memory to draw it to the Canvas as efficiently as possible?

Right now, TS classes that implement my `IDrawable` interface look like this.

```
private Sprite: HTMLImageElement;

public GetImage()
{
    return this.Sprite;
}
public LoadImage(src: string)
{
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    this.Sprite = image;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to be rude, but I removed the last part of the question as it doesn't help understand the problem.

Comment: Honestly this is pretty close to what I do already.  For animated sprites I simply have a PNG that contains all frames, so when I `drawImage` I use an offset and a crop.  The biggest bump to performance you can achieve is by using a WebGL canvas approach, but that is typically best left to frameworks such as pixi.js (which is just the underlying canvas framework) or phaser.js (which is built on top of pixi.js and includes more "game stuff").  Good Luck!

Comment: @federico, its my first question so I was expecting something like that to happen. No bother what-so-ever. :)

Comment: @CaptEmulation so its safe to assume that it's probably not a major performance hit overall. Would storing a secondary canvas I can copy from be better or just a waste of code?

Comment: If you are using typescript your big problem will be language overhead, especially if you use inheritance. Typescript forces you into a style of coding that is not at all CPU friendly. The illusory benefits of strong type and classes is not worth the overhead when quality is governed by performance rather than the body corporate's need to stay safe.

Comment: @Blindman67 given it compiles down to browser safe JS, you'll have to elaborate about TS's language overhead. Do you mean it's module system? A class in JS is just syntactic sugar over it's prototype system so is that fundimentally broken to cause high overhead? I don't notice any extra memory or CPU overhead vs an earlier version that was vanilla JS.

Comment: @benanderson89 it forces you to be type safe for classes, you can not write high performance code if you can not change object structures. TS does not let you reuse an object as a different type even if it shares most of the properties. You must destroy the object and create a new one, this has major performance implications when writing real-time games.

Comment: @Blindman67 IMHO That's only an issue if you don't write your application in a type safe manner. If you DO want your object to be dynamic in TypeScript, you merely specify that its type is "any" (for EG: `var o = <any>{}`) and you get vanilla JS behaviour. If you have two objects that share properties then put those shared properties in an Interface and have both objects implement it, or have one object extend the other as a base class. My character and environment objects both implement `IDrawable`, as an example, thus both can be used in my draw service which expects a type of `IDrawable`.

Comment: @benanderson89 That begs the question why use TS in the first place if you are going to turn it off? .No object need implement `Drawable` it need only a `x`,`y`, I draw with `draw(obj)` not `obj.draw()`, as its much faster, I don't need to add behavior,my object can be pooled, reused, with properties added and/or mutated as needed. The object image property may be a `String` one time and its text, or `Path2D` and its a path The x and y may be `Number`, or sometimes `Arrays` For games ever cycle counts, every GC hit matters, and type safety gets in the way.

Comment: @Blindman67 I'm not "turning it off", nor I have written my application in such a way where X and Y may be either a number or an array (that's bad practice, even in vanilla JS). I've removed that ambiguity via interfaces and strict typing. I also do not use a `obj.draw()` structure, I use a `draw(obj)` structure inside `DrawService`, it accepts any object that implements `IDrawable`. If you're privy, the exact method signature for sprites is: `private DrawSpriteExplicit(image: HTMLImageElement, x: number, y: number, sx: number, sy: number, ssy: number)`. This compiles into very lean JS.